# "Real time" app or near to it

Tags: sockets, real-time

For example we have an application which mission is:

1. User send data to server ( Here is all clear )
2. Server send data to client

With mobile devices all is clear. My server send data to Push Server, then Push Server send data to device and after that, device go to server and download data from server.

But what to do with Browser Extensions, Mac OS Apps or Windows Programs? Here I see two variants:

1) Request data from server every x seconds. What will not be "real-time" if we will use 30 seconds interval for example, but if we will request data every 2 seconds with 10 000 clients (for example) it will look like a self-ddos attack.

2) Using sockets. I know that sockets is good for chat apps, but if our app is not a chat, for example we will send data each 5-60 minutes or more. As I read articles about many performance test on sockets, using socket server with a big amount of people (let's imagine about 1-10 thousand connections) requires a lot of resourses.

Maybe I'm missing something, or what other options are available for this case.
Can you please direct me to the right way. How send data to client as quick as possible?

Comment: Socket is an endpoint for ANY inter-network communication. So by any approach you choose you will be having sockets implicitly or explicitly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Cache frequently sent data so that database calls and other
   processing can be avoided.
2. Use equipment suitable for high volume network traffic and servers that can handle high load
3. Drop traffic when your server is absolutely too busy to handle it
4. If possible, program clients so that they will connect at various intervals - not all at once.
5. Maintain multiple servers and use a load balancer to distribute requests. A simple way to do load balancing is using DNS round robin - I'm not saying you should, just throwing it out there.